# Vue3/Jest - Line break problem during a test

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3

I tried to simulate a mouseover in my test, but i have a problem when i use .contain in an expect. The test doesn't pass because of the page render.

Here the result of the test:

```
Expected substring: "<div id=\"title\"><!--v-if--></div>"
Received string:    "<div id=\"title\">
  <!--v-if-->
</div>"
```

Here my code:

```
describe('mouse event', function() {


test('over change', async (done) => {
    const Component = defineComponent({
      template: '<div id="title" @mouseover="hoveredIcon"><span v-if="hovered">Hello World</span></div>',
      data() {
        return {
          hovered: false,
        }
      },
      methods: {
        hoveredIcon() {
          this.hovered = true
        },
      }
    })
    const wrapper = mount(Component)
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('"<div id=\"title\"><!--v-if--></div>"')
    wrapper.find("#title").trigger("mouseover");
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick( () => {
      expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('<div id=\"title\"><span>Hello World!</span></div>')
      done();
    });
  })
})
```

How can i get the received string on a single line? Or how to made the expect part in few line to match perfectly?

```
expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('<div id="title"><!--v-if--></div>')
```

to

```
expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('<div id="title">
      <!--v-if-->
      </div>')
```

Any better solutions?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution found was to use directly \n directly in the value expected.
expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('\n  \n')